# NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' while web scrapping

Tags: web-scraping

I try to web-scrap the news data using beautiful soup getting a Nonetype attribute error.
Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d288f07b930a> in <module>
     29 
     30     for link in data_array_tcs:
---> 31         title_all = link.find("strong").text
     32         # news_all = link.find(class_="FL").text
     33         date_all = link.find(class_="PT3 a_10dgry").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `link.find("strong")` returned `None`,
as the HTML contained no matches.

You need to test for that, perhaps with an `if` statement,
so you only ask for `.text` in situations where in fact it exists.