# None attribute error while webscrapping using Beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXS9F.png)

Error while trying to do web scrapping

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d288f07b930a> in <module>
     29 
     30     for link in data_array_tcs:
---> 31         title_all = link.find("strong").text
     32         # news_all = link.find(class_="FL").text
     33         date_all = link.find(class_="PT3 a_10dgry").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Trying to retrieve news using web scrapping from money-control site but receiving an none type attribute error

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate and there is still an answer to a fewer asked question - [NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' while web scrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750473/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-while-web-scrapping) Please avoid question spam instead improve your question as recommended in the comments.